# MySQL: query'ing results [pic]

Tags: mysql

I almost have the data I want...but need help filtering it.  (pic at bottom)

The query below returns all records with a status of Member-id5 but I need to filter that. Ex: If I did a simple query on ect. (**exp_channel_titles**) for **author_id** 323 I would get 5 results. Of those 5 results one row has `status = 'Member-id5'`, another one has a `status = 'complete'` AND `title = %Member%` (that's the deciding factor, the row with complete and Member in it). If that row exist then its okay to grab the entry_id of row `status = Member-id5` to use for looking up the data in ecd (exp_channel_data) with  in it. Any idea on how i can do that? picture enclosed

```
SELECT
             ect.entry_id
        ,    ect.author_id
        ,    ect.title
        ,    ect.status
        ,    ecd.field_id_13
        ,    ecd.field_id_14
        ,    ecd.field_id_15
        ,    ecd.field_id_25
        ,    ecd.field_id_27
        ,    ecd.field_id_28
        ,    ecd.field_id_29
        ,    ecd.field_id_30
        ,    ecd.field_id_31
        ,    ecd.field_id_32
        ,    ecd.field_id_33
        ,    ecd.field_id_34
        ,    ecd.field_id_35
        ,    exm.email
    FROM exp_channel_titles as ect
    LEFT JOIN exp_channel_data as ecd
      ON ecd.entry_id = ect.entry_id
    LEFT JOIN exp_members as exm
      ON exm.member_id = ect.author_id
WHERE ect.status = 'Members-id5'
```

[image]

The picture is just of a simple query done on exp_channel_titles, of 323 as author_id. its to show how there multiple results and what entry_id i'm trying to get in order to finish my query. entry_id 496 is what I want, and that based on 1. there is a row with %Member% and complete in it. And then row 496 has a status of Members-id5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ...
FROM exp_channel_titles as ect
  JOIN exp_channel_titles as ect2
    ON (
          ect2.author_id = ect.author_id
      AND ect2.title LIKE '%Member%'
      AND ect2.status = 'complete'
    )
  ...
WHERE ect.status = 'Members-id5'
```

Comment: the results are with entry_id = 505 hmm... i needs to grab entry_id 496 row. it should just use the row with 505 as the entry_id as a reference to check to see if its okay to grab the row with Members-id5 (496) in it. Do a query on the author_id IF there is a row with  %Member% and complete then its okay to grab the entry_id from the row with Members-id5 in it.

Comment: @acctman: In that case, you need to join your `exp_channel_titles` to the query a second time as shown in my updated answer above.